# Expected ',' joining parts of a multi-clause condition

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm trying to write a multi-part guard statement like so:

```
guard let killSwitchedFeatures = quickAuthCardAccount.killswitches, !self.isKillswitched(usingArray: killSwitchedFeatures) else {
    return
}
```

However, this gives me the error `Expected ',' joining parts of a multi-clause condition.` Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? I'm still fairly new-ish to Swift, but can see from examples online that this at least used to be possible.

I'm using Xcode 8 beta 5 if that makes any difference

Edit: Here's the definition of the `isKillswitched` method:

```
private func isKillswitched(usingArray killswitchArray: [String]) -> Bool
```

And here is the definition of the `killswitches` property:

```
public let killswitches: [String]?
```

Comment: What is the signature of `isKillswitched`?

Comment: In Swift 3 your syntax is correct, so long as `self.isKillSwitched...` is a `Bool` (and not a `Bool?`). Swift errors can often pick up a red herring rather than the real problem, which is why @AhmedBaracat has asked for the declaration of the function...

Comment: I just updated my original post with the declaration of `isKillswitched`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I am glad that your problem is solved. But without a clear problem statement and a reproducible example, both question and answer are useless to future readers of this Q&A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try to make the second clause in new line (no official document found, so be awared. But can try with it:).

I read this article about the change made in swift 3: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0099-conditionclauses.md

Comment: No, there is no need to put the clauses in different lines. `guard x == 0, let y = optional, z == 2 else` is given as example in the linked-to proposal.

Comment: @MartinR This is a counter example. The line above it says "disallowing"

Comment: Well, this solved the issue, so while it may or may not be the answer that correctly fixes the base issue, it did allow me to build. Maybe it's because I'm starting with a `let` keyword whereas you start with an equality test?

Comment: @Surely: That is valid code, given as example under *"After adoption of these changes, the previous example would be written in any of these styles:"* The proposal says nothing about putting the clauses into different lines.

Comment: *"you need to make the second clause (each one after comma) in new line"* is definitely wrong. Please try it yourself (I did)!

Comment: Example: `func foo(o: NSObject) { guard let i = o as? NSNumber, i.intValue > 0 else { return } ; print(i) }` – all in one line.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for your experiment. I currently don't have a  Swift 3 environment to test it. I would definitely do it after the official release of Swfit 3. And sorry for the misleading information if I am wrong!